# rails: "Sign In" and "Password Authentication" of Users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im trying to set up a log-in and password page for my site. This will be on the index page. I have a Model Class: "User" and a controller class "users_controller".

The behavior that Im trying to implement is this: 
Users type in the url of the site and it opens the index page as shown below. Then the users signs in and is brought to a different page where they have access to the content of the site.

Now the question is what do I need to put in the "def index" function so that it accepts the form's paramters and passes these to another function called "self.authenticate(parameters)" to check and return a status

[image]

Here is the code for the users_controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

def index
    @user = User.new 

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html 
        #index.html.erb
   end
end


def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @title = @user.name
end

def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @title = @user.name
end

def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def new
    @user = User.new 
    @title = "Sign Up"

end

def create

end
```

end

Here is the form:

```
<html>

<h1>Returning Users- Sign In</h1>
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

<div class="field"> 
    <%=f.label :email %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
</div>

<div class = "field">
    <%= f.label :password %><br/>
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
</div>

<div class = "actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign In"  %>
</div>
<% end %>



<h1>New Users- Sign Up</h1>
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

<div class="field"> 
    <%=f.label :name %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>
<div class="field"> 
    <%=f.label :email %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
</div>

<div class = "field">
    <%= f.label :password %><br/>
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
</div>

<div class = "field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm Password"  %><br/>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
</div>

<div class = "actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign Up"  %>
</div>

<%end%> 


    <br/>
<%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
<br/>

    </body>
```

Any help would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the recent RailsCast [Authentication from Scratch](http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch-revised) from Ryan Bates. You can also use a common authentication plugin like [AuthLogic](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic) or [Devise](http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise).

Comment: Would be great if there were any free resources. The above link you suggest is a pay for view link.

Comment: That RailsCast link is now subscribers only, you're right, but the Authlogic and Devise links aren't.  Google either of them for tutorials etc.  I'd strongly advise using AuthLogic or similar instead of rolling your own authentication because a) it's not fun b) it's nothing to do with the unique features of your app c) you'll probably cock it up.  No offense, it's just much harder to get absolutely right than you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to explain to you what you want to do.

You can get the params by using the hash params:

```
params[]
```

Then, you can get the value of a field by passing it's identification, like:

```
params[:id]
```

or

```
params[:name]
```

Now pass it to the `self.authenticate(parameters)` in the way you can(I don't know how this method is implemented).